# Problems embedding tooltips in SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am a minimalist and I am working in a site which has some restrictions. For these reasons, I want interactive tooltips when people hover over key areas of my SVG, but I also want to embed that interactivity inside the SVG itself. As a further complication, I am not very familiar with Javascript. I initially tried to do this with CSS only but unfortunately, I found that when you embed the CSS inside of your SVG, you cannot use all of the awesomeness of CSS. It is a subset that you can use, and that subset does not give you those awesome tooltips.

So I started looking into Javascript, which you can also embed in the SVG. I really like the tooltips that I am getting so much more than the ones that I get using the title tag. However, there are still issues.

One of the issues is that the following SVG file renders in Chrome, but not Firefox. Firefox does not render it at all and I cannot determine why.

The other problem is that even when it renders in Chrome I still have a problem because I need to have some fairly long tooltips. And the multiline tooltip is not handled well here. Any tips are appreciated!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="oidc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 422 339.2">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st13 {
        fill:#d9489b
    }
    .st13:hover {
        cursor:help;
        fill:#E66E31;
    }
    #tooltip {
          dominant-baseline: hanging;
          font-size: 8px;
      }
  </style>
  <switch>
    <g>
    <g>
      <circle class="st13" cx="47.8" cy="69.2" r="6" data-tooltip-text="I am some fairly long text." />
      <circle class="st13" cx="321.2" cy="65.7" r="6" data-tooltip-text="I am some much much much much much much longer text, so long that I cannot discuss or itemize my exact length....it's looooong, very long. I can't say more."/>
    </g>
    <g id="tooltip" visibility="hidden" transform="translate(87.9511512134412 127.90914747977598)">
      <rect x="2" y="2" width="52.90066909790039" height="24" fill="black" opacity="0.4" rx="2" ry="2"></rect>
      <rect width="52.90066909790039" height="24" fill="lightblue" rx="2" ry="2"></rect>
      <text x="4" y="6">A box</text>
    </g>
  </g>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
  (function() {
      var svg = document.getElementById("oidc");
      var tooltip = svg.getElementById("tooltip");
      var tooltipText = tooltip.getElementsByTagName("text")[0];
      var tooltipRects = tooltip.getElementsByTagName("rect");
      var triggers = svg.getElementsByClassName("st13");

      for (var i = 0; i &lt; triggers.length; i++) {
        triggers[i].addEventListener("mousemove", showTooltip);
        triggers[i].addEventListener("mouseout", hideTooltip);
      }

      function showTooltip(evt) {
        var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
        var x = (evt.clientX - CTM.e + 6) / CTM.a;
        var y = (evt.clientY - CTM.f + 20) / CTM.d;
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate(" + x + " " + y + ")");
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");

        tooltipText.firstChild.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "data-tooltip-text");
        var length = tooltipText.getComputedTextLength();
        for (var i = 0; i &lt; tooltipRects.length; i++) {
          tooltipRects[i].setAttributeNS(null, "width", length + 8);
        }
      }

      function hideTooltip(evt) {
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
      }
    })()
    </script>
  </switch>
</svg>
```

Comment: You may put the script within a [CDATASection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CDATASection)

Comment: You may also use [the <title> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title) instead of tooltips

Comment: "The [`<switch>` SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/switch) evaluates the requiredFeatures, requiredExtensions and systemLanguage attributes on its direct child elements in order, and then processes and renders the first child for which these attributes evaluate to true."

Comment: Removing the `<switch>` gets me into Firefox, that was it, thanks @robert-longson! Now to handle the multiline case. :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the `<script>` element and its contents outside the `<switch>` element.

You don't really need the `<switch>` element at all so you could simply remove it altogether.

This is a Firefox bug but it's an edge case and easily worked around, most people don't put scripts in switch elements.